# VMWare Update Manager - Cannot download files from patch store

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

We're having some issues with the VMWare Update Manager at the moment. To start with the service wasn't starting at all. I tracked that down to an XML issue in one of the many config files (`jetty-vum-ssl.xml`). The Update Manager service is now running however whenever we go to scan a host we get:

`Host cannot download files from VMware vSphere Update Manager patch store`

Having a look in `/var/log/esxupdate.log` I can see the following:

```
Command: scan
Args: ['scan']
Options: {'nosigcheck': None, 'retry': 5, 'loglevel': None, 'cleancache': None, 'viburls': None, 'meta': ['http://172.16.0.243:9084/vum/repository/hostupdate/csco/csco-VEM-5.5.0-metadata.zip', 'http://172.16.0.243:9084/vum/repository/hos
2018-01-18T08:35:42Z esxupdate: BootBankInstaller.pyc: INFO: Unrecognized value "title=Loading VMware ESXi" in boot.cfg^@
2018-01-18T08:35:42Z esxupdate: vmware.runcommand: INFO: runcommand called with: args = '['/sbin/bootOption', '-rp']', outfile = 'None', returnoutput = 'True', timeout = '0.0'.^@
2018-01-18T08:35:42Z esxupdate: vmware.runcommand: INFO: runcommand called with: args = '['/sbin/bootOption', '-ro']', outfile = 'None', returnoutput = 'True', timeout = '0.0'.^@
2018-01-18T08:35:42Z esxupdate: downloader: DEBUG: Downloading http://172.16.0.243:9084/vum/repository/hostupdate/csco/csco-VEM-5.5.0-metadata.zip to /tmp/tmp1Ccual...^@
2018-01-18T08:35:43Z esxupdate: esxupdate: ERROR: An esxupdate error exception was caught:^@
2018-01-18T08:35:43Z esxupdate: esxupdate: ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):^@
2018-01-18T08:35:43Z esxupdate: esxupdate: ERROR:   File "/usr/sbin/esxupdate", line 216, in main^@
2018-01-18T08:35:43Z esxupdate: esxupdate: ERROR:     cmd.Run()^@
2018-01-18T08:35:43Z esxupdate: esxupdate: ERROR:   File "/build/mts/release/bora-6480324/bora/build/esx/release/vmvisor/sys-boot/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vmware/esx5update/Cmdline.py", line 105, in Run^@
2018-01-18T08:35:43Z esxupdate: esxupdate: ERROR:   File "/build/mts/release/bora-6480324/bora/build/esx/release/vmvisor/sys-boot/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vmware/esximage/Transaction.py", line 73, in DownloadMetadatas^@
2018-01-18T08:35:43Z esxupdate: esxupdate: ERROR: MetadataDownloadError: ('http://172.16.0.243:9084/vum/repository/hostupdate/csco/csco-VEM-5.5.0-metadata.zip', None, "('http://172.16.0.243:9084/vum/repository/hostupdate/csco/csco-VEM-5.
2018-01-18T08:35:43Z esxupdate: esxupdate: DEBUG: <<<^@
```

It looks like it is trying to connect to the correct location but there doesn't appear to be anything bound to the port its trying to access: `9084`. It doesn't look like there are any other services that haven't started that would bind to that port. The firewall is off on the target machine currently so we can hopefully rule that out. A `netstat -an | find 9084` produces 0 results.

Does anyone know what chunk of the VMWare architecture is meant to be listening on 9084 or have any suggestion of where I should be looking next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up reinstalling the Update Manager (and upgrading vCenter Server at the same time). That appears to have fixed the problem but no idea as to what the original problem was.